# C# get current directory without having to specify full path?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-4.0, .net-4.5

I'm currently trying to create some files within the same folder as my handler file. Everything is working right now but I don't want to have to specify the full path every time I want to use it, and this path will be different depending on where i"m running the program.

Is there a way where I can just get the current directory and add whatever I want onto it? I tried `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` but this returned `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv` which is no where close to where my app is.

Any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: @ScottChamberlain reopened

Comment: Thanks, I switched it to the other duplicate